# I don't understand operator precedence in python True and False or True

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, operator-precedence

It says in python 2.7 docs that `or` has lower precedence than `and`. But when I type in idle this:

```
>>> True and True or False
True
>>> True and False or True
True
>>> True and False
False
```

Why is the result of this `True and False or True` expression `True`?

Comment: Because... that's how `or` works? (`or True` will always be `True`)

Comment: In this case, without any parenthesis, precedence is equal, so values are evaluated from left to right, `True and False or True` = `(True and False) or True` = `False or True` = `True`.

Comment: I had a couple of statements in "if" clause with some "not" operators and made some mistakes. How to delete question ? :) And thank you for answers.

Comment: @Rogalski: Precedence is not equal. In this particular example, operations *are* evaluated from left to right, but that's pure coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Higher precedence means that an operator would be evaluated before an operator with lower precedence, like, e.g., in arithmetic, multiplication should evaluated before addition, so `1 + 2 * 3` will result in `7` and not `9`.

In your usecase, `True and False` is evaluated first, giving `False`. This result is then evaluated with the `or` operator (i.e., `False or True`), resulting in `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, operator precedence has nothing to do with this result; it would be the same wherever you put the parentheses, since `or` always returns True if either of its arguments are true. So:

```
True and (False or True) == True and (True) == True
(True and False) or True == (False) or True == True
```

Answer (score 1):

You statement is asking to do the following

First python evaluates the expression on the left;

Evaluation 1: True and false (Since this evaluates to false python then looks to the or expression)

Evaluation 2: True or false

Which then evaluates to true

You may also want to take a look at Boolean logic and truth tables to assist with understanding how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Highest precedence means where you will put the parentheses

```
((True and True) or False)  # True
((True and False) or True)  # True
(True and False)            # False
```